Jaw-breaking sum (related to quasi-analytic decompositions of unity — and Hörmander’s Lemma 1.3.6 from LinPDE vol.1)
$$F\left(\frac 1{\text e}\right) ≈ 1-\frac 1{\text e};\qquad\text{here }F(z)≔\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{k!}z^k.$$
The match is at least with 800 decimal places (checked with sumnum of gp/PARI) — and probably is up to 1,300 places (suggested by sumnummonien of gp/PARI with \p 1600 — but it is not very reliable; more precision would require hours of calculations and tens of GBs of memory).  Obviously, $1/\text e$ is on the boundary of the disk of convergence, and the sum converges with the residual $O(\frac 1{\sqrt k})$.
Update: there is a solution in the comment by Nemo.
Motivation: trying to understand Lemma 1.3.6 (see also) of vol.1 of Linear PDE by Hörmander.  It estimates from below the possible width of a cut-off function with given “quasi-analytic bounds”.  AFAICS, this lemma deals with estimating $F(1/4)$ (or something very similar — or majorated by $F$) from above by 1.
(Well, I cheated: the lemma is to establish majoration by something similar to $F$, not the estimate itself.  But the Taylor series given above is the result of pushing Hörmander’s argument “to its limits”.)

Trying to prove this (using the motivations above) I get to even more jaw-falling-off coincidences. — But they deserve separate considerations — and so far have not led to a logically satisfactory proof.

To remove all the flavored words, you just want a proof or disproof of $F(\frac{1}{e}) = 1 - \frac{1}{e}$?

@AlekseiKulikov This would be a nice first step.  I would not mind also backward and forward references related to L.1.3.6, though!  (The book contains only very coarse estimates for the support of a cut-off function.)

@Nemo Wow!  I recognized the relation to $x\text{e}^x$, but did not think about considering the inverse function (which I use a lot in other contexts, drat)!  A lot of thanks!

This is direct consequence of  $\left(\frac{W_0(x)}{x}\right)^r=e^{-rW_0(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r(n+r)^{n-1}}{n!}(-x)^n$, where $|x|<1/e$, (with $r=-1$) and $W_0(-1/e)=-1$ for the Lambert W-function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Other_formulas.
